# How to prevent the values of properties initialized by the constructor from being overwritten

Tags: c#, encapsulation

I am new to programming and am trying to prevent the `Program` class from overwriting the values of the properties that were initialized by the constructor of the `Person` class

Here is my code: please see the comments highlighting what I am trying to achieve

```cs
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person
        {
            public string FName { get; set; }
            public string LName { get; set; }

            public Person(string fName, string lName)
            {
                FName = fName;
                LName = lName;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return FName + " " + LName;
            }

        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Person person = new Person("Adam", "Lake");
            person.FName = "Fabio";      // I want to prevent this 
            person.LName = "Scagliola";  // I want to prevent this 
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're actively causing the problem by performing the overwrite; did you intend to create two Person objects? Or is this literally you wondering how to make properties ReadOnly so that when you do you will see a compiler error that the Steve/Stoogie lines are impossible (I'm wondering what the problem is; that you don't know how to make two people or that you don't know how to make properties read only)

Comment: @CaiusJard - Yes the idea is to throw a compile error when trying to run the Steve Stoogie lines because it shouldn't be there and it should only display Adam Lake. I need a compile error to prevent the program from running if any name is used other than Adam Lake. I think I may have sorted it now though :)

Comment: The easiest and fastest way to achieve your goal is to protect the setters: `public string FirstName { get; protected set; } public string LastName { get; protected set; }`

Comment: @FabioScagliola I disagree. What if another class derives from `Person`? You can still change that property, not what the user wants.

Comment: @zaggler, I believe Adam is trying to encapsulate the first and the last name in order to prevent the `Program` class from overwriting them. If so, my proposed solution will work. I agree with you, though: this will not prevent derived classes from overwriting the first and the last name. Anyway, I am in the process to try and improve this question and request to consider it for reopening, because the **encapsulation** topic is interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you properties `FirstName` and `LastName` to [Read-only Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

```
public string FirstName { get; }
public string LastName { get; }
```

It means that you can only set the value from the `Person` constructor

Comment: Thank you for that. I did as mentioned but I am getting the following error:

Property or indexer 'Person.FirstName' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Have you encountered this before? :)

Comment: Isn't that what you *wanted*?

Comment: @Adam because thats exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @zaggler - Yes sorry I think this should be what I am after. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This made me laugh; 

Comment: @Adam what you now need to do is click the grey check mark to turn it green. This changes the appearance of the question of the dashboard and lets people know you're no longer looking for an answer

Comment: @CaiusJard - that should hopefully be marked off now. Sorry I am new to stack overflow.